# Convert NSNumber to String to support .sort() method in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsarray, nsnumber

I am receiving some Dictionary data which contains keys 'description'and 'volume'. I need to sort the dictionary based upon that and assign it to an array which will in turn load my UITableView.

I am able to sort based on description with `nameArr.append((unSortedHoldingsArr[i]["description"] as? String).initializeStringIfNil)` 
where nameArr is declared as var `nameArr : [String] = []` but when i am trying to sort it based upon volume the nameArr is getting filled with blank data. I am assuming the 'volume' contains data in NSNumber format. I want to make sure any kind of data coming from dictionary should get converted to String format to support the data in array.

Comment: Did you try the "\\(value)" syntax?

Comment: Yes @NicolasMiari

Comment: If it's an NSNumber instance, it should give you the string representation. You said you "assume" it is an `NSNumber`; did you make sure (e.g. in the debugger)?